# access repeater control and change their properties

Tags: ms-access, controls, repeater

I am trying to either disable / hide the lnkDelete button that is located inside repeater control. I used this method, however I get an error message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   I am not sure what seems to be the problem. I am able to use intellesense to show the Visible property of the control, this proof to me that I do have scope to the control inside the repeater, anyone can help.
thanks

```
    protected void rptCAP_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var lnkDel = e.Item.FindControl("lnkDelete").Visible = false;
      }
```

Bob white

Comment: What do you mean by repeater control?  Also that isn't VBA code.

Comment: Do you expect us to read your mind about what environment you're coding in? Based on tags, one would expect you're programming in Access VBA, but you're clearly not. GIVE US SOME HELP HERE IF YOU WANT IT IN RETURN.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an if statement to check if the itemtype is an item or alternating item and not header item or footer item:

```
If (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){
 var lnkDel = e.Item.FindControl("lnkDelete").Visible = false;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bob it would seem you're trying to set the Visible property even when the FindControl doesn't return a control.

You should probably do something like

```
var lnkDel = e.Item.FindControl("lnkDelete");
if (lnkDel != null)
  lnkDel.Visible = false;
```